# Is there a way to enable grid tuning of mtry using Random Forest and PCA pre-processing in train function from Caret?

Tags: r, r-caret

When I use Random Forest with PCA pre-processing with the train function from Caret package, if I add a `expand.grid(ncomp=c(2,5,10,15))`, I need to provide also a grid for mtry.

```
res <- train(Y~., data=df, method="icr", preProc = c("center",
"scale"), tuneGrid = expand.grid(n.comp = c(2,5,10,15))))
```

I would rather not provide it and let it work as it is when I perform the same Random Forest with PCA pre-processing without specifying any `expand.grid`.

```
res <- train(Y~., data=df, method="icr", preProc = c("center",
"scale")))
```

Does any one know how I can solve this ?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer, I post it for someone interest.
You need to add the ICA parameter in the trainControl because ICA is use for pre-processing.

`fitControl <-(preProcOptions = list(ICAcomp = 2))
 res <- train(Y~., data=df, method="icr", preProc = c("center","scale")))`

Unfortunatly, I don't think you can give a grid for ICA comp in this case

Answer (score 0):

`n.comp` isn't exposed to the `preProcess` function when you call it from `train`.

One alternative is to use a custom method. [Here](http://topepo.github.io/caret/custom_models.html#Illustration4) is an example that does *almost* exactly what you want (but uses PLS instead of PCA).

Max